# Elegant way of finding all integer element indices in a MATLAB array?

Tags: matlab

I have a double array containing a mixture of integers and doubles. I wish to get all the indices of the integer elements. My way (see below) is quite ugly.

```
idx_list = [];
for idx = 1:numel(A)
    if isinteger(A(idx))
        idx_list = [idx_list idx];
    end
end
```

I believe there is a one liner / a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would find *perfect* integers -

```
idx_list = find( floor(A) == A )
```

Changing **[`floor`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html)** to **[`ceil`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html)** or **[`round`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html)** or **[`fix`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html)** should do it too.

If you want to take care of floating point precision issues, you can introduce **[`eps`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)** here -

```
idx_list = find(abs(round(A) - A)<eps(round(A)))
```

Comment: why not find(floor(A) == A) ?  It seems the same, just easier to read.